# Compare in Python / PyRanges two genomic intervals to determine whether they're separate, partially overlapping, or contained

Tags: python, pandas, interval, pyranges

As part of a larger analysis, I need to evaluate pairs of genomic regions (`regionsA` and `regionsB`) and perform different calculations for each pair depending on whether:

1. They're completely separate (no overlap)
2. `regionsB` partially overlaps `regionsA` (start or end of `regionsB` does not overlap; both are handled separately)
3. `regionsB` is fully contained in `regionsA`

At this time, `regionsA` and `regionsB` are represented as Pandas DataFrames. Likewise, I'm doing all possible combinations:

```
if (region_b.start < region_a.start and
    region_b.end < region_b.start):
[...]
elif (region_b.start < region_a.start and
     (region_b.end > region_a.start
     and region_b.end < region_a.end )):
```

Given that there are many conditions I check for, this makes the code long, a little hard to read, and too verbose. Is there anything I can use (without making the code harder to read) to make these checks simpler, something like PyRanges (or PyRanges itself, although I don't think there's API for it)?

If not, I'll just live with what I have.